# Promise on Express router don't work twice

Tags: node.js, express, promise, nested, router

I’m a beginner on Node.js and Express (or rather passage).
It’s simple, I tried to do an email check by nesting two routers. And it works, but when I try a second time without restarting the server, it works half:
I receive the email, the router receives the confirmation when I confirm the email, the router displays "Email verification success" on the browser, then nothing. No error message but the rest of the instructions are not read (everything in the "try/catch").
However, when I wait for the end of the setTimout, the catch condition activates and executes the instructions in the catch. I do not understand

```
router.post('/send', async (req, res) => {

    const token = jwt.sign({ //Creation of the JsonWebToken
        data: 'Token Data' 
    }, 'MySecretKey', { expiresIn: '5m' }   
    );  

    const mailConfigurations = { 

        // It should be a string of sender/server email 
        from: 'no-reply-please@mygame.fr', 
        
        //User mail to verify
        to: req.body.emailPretension, 
        
        // Subject of Email 
        subject: 'Vérification', 
            
        html:`<body>...</body>`,    
    }; 

    transporter.sendMail(mailConfigurations, function(error, info){ 
        if (error) throw Error(error); 
        console.log('Email Sent Successfully');  
    });

    let WaitConfirmation = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            router.get('/response', async (req, res) => {
                const tokenReceived = req.query.token; 

                jwt.verify(tokenReceived, 'MySecretKey', function(err, decoded) { 
                    if(err){
                        res.send("Email verification failed, possibly the link is invalid or expired");
                        reject("Email verification failed, possibly the link is invalid or expired");
                    } 
                    else{
                        resolve("Email verifified successfully");
                        res.send("Email verification success");
                    } 
                }); 
            })
            setTimeout(()=>{
                reject();
            },300000) //300 000 = 5min
        })
    }
    try{
        let test = await WaitConfirmation();
        res.json({response:true});
    }
    catch{
        console.log(Error response");
    }

});
```

I tried with several devices, nothing. I tried to vary the router name with router.get('/response/:token'), nothing. I tried to stop nesting the routers too, but I don't have the skills to do it.

Comment: Why are you creating a route dynamically on every request to `send`?  This is an odd (and currently broken) way to see if they reply to an email within five minutes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your remark but for me it was the only way to succeed in ensuring that the async function in the frontend is the one which sends and receives the response from the user. What should I do ?